# React : Why is my id undefined ? axios.post request deletes data instead of updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

Thanks to the community I resolved my dynamic id issue for the axios.get with `${this.props.match.params.id}` and I can access my edit-form for each product.

Unfortunately this trick seems to be inefficient for the post request and I'm stuck. When I submit my form the `axios.post` in my `handleSubmit` deletes my previous data instead of updating with the new one. I can see that the sql request has undefined data and especially the `id`, I don't understand why..

I'm kind of a rookie in React, so could you suggest me how to fix my post request.

I provide you my edit-form, and some of the node back maybe it's relevant.

EditForm

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class EditForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { product: [] };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    };
    
    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios
        .get(`/products/edit-form/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.products);
            this.setState({
                product: response.data.products
            })
        });    
    };

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({id: e.target.value})
        this.setState({reference: e.target.value})
        this.setState({designation: e.target.value})        
    }

     handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        const data = { 
        id: this.state.id,
        reference: this.state.reference,
        designation: this.state.designation        
        }  

        axios
        .post(`/products/${data.id}`, data )
        .then(res => console.log(res))      
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
 
    renderForm() {
        return this.state.product.map((product, index) => {
            const { id,reference,designation } = product
        return(
            <>         
            <Form className="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridReference">
                    <Form.Label>Reference</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={reference} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="reference"  />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridDesignation">
                    <Form.Label>Designation</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={designation} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="designation"  />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>                

                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
            </>
            );
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Formulaire de modification</h1>
                {this.renderForm()}
            </div>        
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(EditForm);
```

Products

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const headings = [
    'id','reference','designation'
];

export default class Products extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: []
        };
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get("/products").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.products);
            this.setState({
                products: response.data.products
            })
        });
    };
 
    renderTableHeader() {       
        return headings.map((key, index) => {
        return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    } 

    renderProductData() {
        return this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            const { id,reference,designation } = product
            return (
                <tr key={id}>
                    <td>
                        {id}
                        <Link to={`/edit-form/${id}`}>Modifier</Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{reference}</td>
                    <td>{designation}</td>                               
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id='title'>Produits</h1>
                <Table striped bordered hover id='products'>
                    <thead>
                        {this.renderTableHeader()}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderProductData()}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBar />            
                <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Products}/>
                    <Route path="/edit-form/:id" component={EditForm}/>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>  
        );
    }
}
```

Node backend

```
//routes.js

    // Get All
    router.get('/products', getProducts.getProducts);
    // Get sorted
    // router.get('/products/:param', getProducts.getProductsSorted);
    // Get single
    router.get('/products/edit-form/:productId', getProducts.getProduct);
    // Update
    router.post('/products/:productId', getProducts.postProduct);


// productController.js

const getProduct = async (req, res) => 
{
    const { productId } = req.params;
    const product = await productDb.getProduct(productId);
    res.status(200).send({ products: product.rows });    
};

const postProduct = async (req, res) => 
{
    const { productId } = req.params;
    const { reference,designation } = req.body;
    await productDb.updateProduct(productId, reference, designation);
    res.status(200).send(`Le produit reference ${reference} a été modifié`);  
    console.log(`Le produit reference ${reference} a été modifié`); 


// productDb.js

const getProduct = async (id) =>
{
    const connection = new DbConnection();
    return await connection.performQuery(`SELECT * FROM produits WHERE id=${id}`);
};

const updateProduct = async (id, reference, designation) =>
{
    const connection = new DbConnection();
    await connection.performQuery("UPDATE produits SET reference=?, designation=? WHERE id=?", 
    [reference, designation, id]);
};
```

Thank you

Comment: handleChange function must find which element has triggered it and set that specific attribute only. The problem is on evry handleChange call you are resetting the while data, rather you should set only the corresponding attribute.

Comment: Did you meant separate setters like this 
`handleReferenceChange(e) { this.setState({reference: e.target.value})}
    
    handleDesignationChange(e) { this.setState({designation: e.target.value})}`
binded in the constructor and called in the onChange. If so my data still dissapear

Comment: First add a name attribute to each of the Form.control, then access that in the handleChangeFunction, similar to this:

` handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.name === 'isGoing' ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  } `

Answer (score 0):

I would consider checking the state:

```js
 axios
        .get(`/products/edit-form/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.products);
            this.setState({
                product: response.data.products
            })
        });
```

This sets `product` as an array of products

```js
handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({id: e.target.value})
        this.setState({reference: e.target.value})
        this.setState({designation: e.target.value})        
    }
```

This sets state `id, reference, designation` - but note that it reads from the same target value - so if reference text field changes, it'll change id and designation to the same value as per @Asutosh's comment.

```js
 handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        const data = { 
        id: this.state.product.id,
        reference: this.state.product.reference,
        designation: this.state.product.designation        
        };

        axios
        .post(`/products/${this.props.match.params.id}`, data )
        .then(res => console.log(res))      
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
```

This reads from product, but product is an array. However, that doesn't reflect what `handleChange` is setting, which sets `id, reference, designation` in the root. That will cause id, reference, designation to be undefined, because `this.state.product` is an array.

A possible change that can be done is in `handleChange`:

```
        const data = { 
        id: this.state.id,
        reference: this.state.reference,
        designation: this.state.designation        
        };
```

but that will only work if the user has *changed* something in the form. We need to also consider the fact the user might just click submit.

Also, I noticed another error (maybe unrelated? - read comments):

```
  renderForm() {
        return this.state.product.map((product, index) => {
            const { id,reference,designation } = product // is this used?
        return(
            <>         
            <Form className="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridReference">
                    <Form.Label>Reference</Form.Label>
{/* this should be reference instead of this.state.product.reference? why is it set as placeholder? */}
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.product.reference} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="reference" placeholder={reference} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridDesignation">
                    <Form.Label>Designation</Form.Label>
{/* this should be designation instead of this.state.product.designation? Why is designation set as a placeholder instead? */}
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.product.designation} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="designation" placeholder={designation} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>                

                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
            </>
            );
        })
    }
```

---

In addition, if the goal is to submit changes based on a single product of products, I would consider creating a `ProductsList` component, which keeps `componentDidMount`, and then create a `Product` component which has the `handleChange` and `handleSubmit`

Comment: I edited so you can see how I followed your advices and I add my `ProductsList` component.
- For the `const data` modification, you meant `handleSubmit` I guess?
- I use the beginning of my `renderForm` to access my data, otherwise it's not defined.
- the `placeholder` was to display previous data but I don't need it you're right
- If I put `value={reference}` and `value={designation}`, the previous data is displayed but I cannot write any data in my inputs.
- still my post request is not working with `${this.state.id}` or `${this.props.match.params.id}`